# convert month value to an integer in javascript, in order to use getMonth()+1?

Tags: javascript, date, integer, monthcalendar

I wanted to do something like this code, but the date does not let me do it: the alert says "`undefined`" when the month is over 11, such as 12, 13...

I would like to navigate from a month to another, so i would need to do something like `getMonth()+1` or `+2`, even if the current month is December (so that, `December+1 (11+1)` would give me `January (0)` ). Would you know how to achieve this?

```
var m = mdate.getMonth();
    alert(nextMonth(m+3));

    function nextMonth(month){
        if (month>11) {
            if(month==12) month=0;
            if(month==13) month=1;
        } else {
            return month;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: nextMonth just returns month in the usual case. How is that the "next" month?

Comment: I think this would be better using a modulus function. What if you had `nextMonth(123)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the modulus operator to stay within the bounds.

```
function nextMonth(month){
    return month % 12
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use modular division:

```
var m = 11;
alert((m+1) % 12); // 0
alert((m+2) % 12); // 1
```

This is not a very good idea. The built in Date functions in javascript will handle this for you.

```
someDate.setMonth(someDate.getMonth() + m);
```